# Corollary of Wolpert lemma

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Recall Wolpert Lemma. 
Let $S$ be a surface with genus greater than 2, let $[X,f]$ and $[Y,g]$ two points of $T(S)$ (Teichmüller space) and let $\phi \colon X \to Y$ a $K$ quasi conformal homeo. Then we have $$ \frac{l_X(c)}{K}\leq l_Y(\phi(c))\leq Kl_X(c)$$

For any simple closed curve $c$.
Now as an immediate corollary on the Farb Margalit it is given the following.

> Assume $d_T(X,Y)=d$, then for any $c$ as above we have $$ \frac{l_X(c)}{e^{2d}}\leq l_Y(c)\leq e^{2d}l_X(c)$$

The fact why the constant turns out to be the exponential is clear to me (def. Of K), I don't get why in the middle part we don't have $\phi(c)$ for $\phi$ this time a Teichmüller map according to my understandings.

Can we always assume that such map fixes a curve $c$? 
I dont think so, because this would be a contradiction to the classification of elements in $Mod(S)$ according to me.

So how do we get the central term?

Comment: Could you specify which page, please?

Answer (score 1):

You must notice that, in this lemma, we are talking about elements in Teichmuller space,rather than two hyperbolic surfaces. So by the definition of the length function(see Farb-Margalit Page 265),we get exactly l_Y（c）
.